# Read Data Stored as Excel File in Sql Server Table Using T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have an excel file of 28 columns stored in a column of a SqlServer table. Using t-sql, is it possible to read the data from one of the columns in the excel file without exporting it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a binary Excel file stored in a SQL Server table? In a blob column?

Comment: How is the excel file stored? Is it just a reference to the file's location? Is it XML?

Comment: I believe it is base 64 encoded in a varchar column. Sorry I'm not a Sql expert. It's definitely not stored as xml.

Comment: Yikes. Pretty sure the answer is "definitely not".

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL - you have a blob inside the database, you have to extract it if you want to do anything with it. The database doesn't know how to process blobs

Answer (score 0):

Although unstructured, this works:

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2012/09/sql-server-converting-base64-to-varchar.html

-- Convert from base64 to varchar:

DECLARE
    @Encoded VARCHAR(max) = 'VGVzdA==',
    @Decoded VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @Decoded = 
CAST(
    CAST(N'' AS XML).value(
        'xs:base64Binary(sql:column("bin"))'
      , 'VARBINARY(MAX)'
    ) 
    AS VARCHAR(MAX)
) 
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(@Encoded AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS bin
) AS bin_sql_server_temp;
PRINT @Decoded

Comment: Then you'll get the binary contents of a zip file. How is this going to help the OP read a specific column from the spreadsheet?